# Playframework: Dynamic Search Fields

Tags: search, playframework

I need to implement a search dialog within play but don't know to solve this.
I have 3 integer fields in my database and want to search each of them with min and max values:

select * from office
where maxSeats <= maxParamFromPage
and maxSeats >= minParamFromPage
...

All fields are optional so if a user only enters the minParamFromPage all offices should be listed which are higher than this param. Now I have 3 params like maxSeats and I need to buildup my query dynamically based on the input parameters. I thought about replacing them with "0" or null when those are not entered but this is placed one to one in the sql query.

Can somebody help me on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should used JPA Criteria API to construct your criterion based on the form values.

Refer this [example](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria)